# Testing Case for food_search route in python

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, testcase

'I use the route food_search to get data from api and return an array'

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase
from models import db, User

# BEFORE we import our app, let's set an environmental variable
# to use a different database for tests (we need to do this
# before we import our app, since that will have already
# connected to the database

os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = "postgresql:///mealplan_test"
from app import app
class FoodSearchTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

        with self.app.app_context():
            db.drop_all()
            db.create_all()

            # Create a test user and log them in
            user = User(username='testuser', password='testpassword', email='testing@test.com', firstname='fname', lastname='lname')
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            db.drop_all()

    def test_food_search(self):
        with self.client as c:
                response = c.get("/food_search?q=banana")
                self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
                self.assertIn(b'banana', response.data)
```

AssertionError:response.status_code 302 != 200
AssertionError: b'banana' not found in b'\nRedirecting...\n

## Redirecting...

\n

You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /login.  If not click the link.'

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: I tried to test for the response for the food_search route but they return a redirect code 302 instead of code 200

Comment: The API is responding correctly, but with a redirection. So you need to provide the API code to see why another behavior is expected.